# Reg. google cloud vision api

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to read the hand-written data on hot rolled coils using python and google-cloud-vision api. But what i have observed that when the data is written in slightly inclined manner the vision api completely fails. For eg if the data is written as [image: inclined] it completely fails and gives some absurd output even though visibly the data should be ok to read.

However if the data is written as [image: straight] the api reads it correctly.
 Should any  pre-processing for the image needs to be done so that api reads it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Image pre-processing is a good practice on the client side  to improve efficiency, accuracy and response time.*** In fact, it would be particularly important to remove as much noise as possible.The Vision API, however, uses machine learning algorithms that are continuously improved. As far as my knowledge  about image pre-processing techniques, this task is more easily accomplished manually than using standard or advanced image pre-processing. On this [Google cloud vision page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files), you can find a good set of recommendations.

Comment: marginal improvement when storing the files in png format. however preprocessing did not yield good results.